# How to chop ruby string having a random number

Tags: ruby

My string is - `main_string = 'FA117RWD-20 ABC Program (version 10.0)'`

In this string I just want to read FA117RWD-20 and in this string version is random which will be coming from somewhere, its version 10 right now it can be version 20 at some other time also the part that I want to read i.e. FA117RWD-20 will also be coming from somewhere randomly so is not of fix length, basically I want to chop everything that is coming after this string. How should I do it?

Thanks

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve]. [so] is not a "write-my-code-for-me-service"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
main_string = 'FA117RWD-20 ABC Program (version 10.0)'

main_string[/\S+/]
  #=> "FA117RWD-20"
```

The regular expression matches one or more characters that are not whitespace.

Another way is the following<sup>1</sup>.

```
main_string[0..main_string.index(' ')-1]
```

<sup>1 One can use three dots and write `main_string[0...main_string.index(' ')]`, but I prefer to always use two dots.</sup>

Comment: This is a way to go.

Answer (score 1):

you can just use [`#split`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/split)

```
'FA117RWD-20 ABC Program (version 10.0)'.split(' ').first
```

Comment: In the case of a very long string this produces a superfluous array.